# Query alias with INNER JOIN and LIMIT 1

Tags: mysql

I have 3 table:

```
    Message_group
    ---------------------------------------
    message_group_id | profile_id | group_id
    ----------------------------------------

    1                    sN07X2    4934Me
    2                    abcde2    4934Me
    3                    Red3zw    3492Ga
    4                    Hgr43s    3492Eh
    ----------------------------------------

    Private_Message
    ----------------------------------------
    msg_id | msg_txt | profile_id | occured_at
    -----------------------------------------
    1         Hello       abcde2      2013-06-26
    2         Bye Bye     abcde2      2013-06-26
    3         Ciao        Red3zw      2012-06-26|
    -----------------------------------------

   Users
   -------------------------------------------
   profile_id | name | sirname | 
   sN07X2       Jin     OO
   abcde2      Gerry    UU
   Red3zw      Lola     YY
   Hgr43s      Scot     EE
```

I want have the result like that

```
  profile_id | profile_id2 | group_id | msg_text
   abcde2         sN07X2      4934Me     abcde2
```

i would like have this result but like msg_text only the last messege.
this query that i have wrote give me this result, i don't know how add the field msg with limit 1:

```
  profile_id | profile_id2 | group_id |
   abcde2         sN07X2      4934Me
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM message_group a
JOIN message_group b ON a.group_id=b.group_id
INNER JOIN users ON users.profile_id = b.profile_id  
WHERE a.profile_id = 'sN07X2'
AND b.profile_id != a.profile_id
```

Comment: how do you join private_message with message_group?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish. I understand every user belongs to a group. It seems privete message has NO receiver so the model assumes each user only can send a message to a group it belongs and it can only belong to one group? I just don't get the model...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but it could be

```
SELECT a.*,b.*,(SELECT msg_txt FROM Private_Message p WHERE p.profile_id=a.profile_id ORDER BY occured_at DESC LIMIT 1) 
FROM message_group a
JOIN message_group b ON a.group_id=b.group_id
INNER JOIN users ON users.profile_id = b.profile_id  
WHERE a.profile_id = 'sN07X2'
AND b.profile_id != a.profile_id
```

But, I really don't understand your condition : `AND b.profile_id != a.profile_id` ??!!

Comment: Thank you So much! Working perfect the logic. I used AND b.profile_id != a.profile_id because else the result is 2 rows I need only one